# Нет записи в файл .html

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы, python-2.x

Мой код,

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver


def get_data_with_selenium(url):
    global driver
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.set_preference("general.useragent.override", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.1.1 Safari/605.1.15")
    try:
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(
            executable_path="/Users/user/PycharmProjects/pythonProject2/chromedriver/chromedriver",
            options=options
        )
        driver.get(url=url)
        time.sleep(6)

        with open("/Users/user/PycharmProjects/pythonProject2/chromedriver/index_selenium.html", "w", -1) as file:
            file.write(driver.page_source)


    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
    finally:
        driver.close()
        driver.quit()


def main():
    get_data_with_selenium("https://it.integromash.ru")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

ВОПРОС:
нет записи в файл index_selenium.html

Коммент:
использую pycharm community

Скрины проекта:
main.py.   и   index_selenium.html

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас ошибка при записи в файл, которая ловится и выводится в консоли в `except Exception as ex:`.

Сохраняйте файл с указанием кодировки `utf-8`:

```
file_name = "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/pythonProject2/chromedriver/index_selenium.html"
with open(file_name, "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    f.write(driver.page_source)
```

---

**Кст**, если папка проекта `/Users/user/PycharmProjects/pythonProject2/chromedriver` и при запуске скрипта, его рабочая директория такая же, то можно указывать только название файла:

```
file_name = "index_selenium.html"
with open(file_name, "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    f.write(driver.page_source)
```

Comment: Заработало. !!!

Comment: @Михаил, пожалуйста, и не забудьте [проголосовать и принять ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour) :)